# TypeScript omit shared base keys from combined type with hardcoded values

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to create a type that has all possible keys from multiple other types, plus some extra but excluding another (shared) base type.

The problem is that some of the keys have hard set values, when intersecting these types it unfortunately results in type `never`. How do I go about getting a type that has all possible keys?

```
type Base = {
  base: string;
};

type A = Base & {
  type: 1;
};

type B = Base & {
  type: 2;
  notShared: string;
  optional?: string;
};

type New = Omit<A & B, keyof Base> & {
  extra: string;
};

// Unfortunately equivalent to:
// type New = Omit<never, keyof Base> & {
//   extra: string;
// }

const test: New = {
  extra: '',
  type: 1, // Should allow 1 or 2
  notShared: '',
  optional: '',
  q: '', // Should not allow
  base: '', // Should not allow
};
```

Comment: Your title says "intersect types" and you've tagged with "union types" and maybe neither of these are relevant.  You happen to write `A & B` but, as you say, that gives you `never`, which is not useful (and hence you cannot simply intersect them).  And I don't see the a union here either.  Could you edit the title/text/tags to clarify?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5eY5N) meet your needs (where you operate on the union type `A | B`)?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That does seem to work. It looks very complicated though

Comment: Well, what you are doing is not a straightforward manipulation of the types.  Do you want it hard coded for `A | B` or do you want it to work on any union type?

Comment: I want to future proof New so it always contains all the keys from A and B minus Base.

Comment: Right, I understand that.  My question was whether you will want to be able to do this with types *other* than just `A` and `B` (e.g., `AllProps<A | B | C>` or `AllProps<D | E>`) or if you are okay hardcoding `A` and `B` in there.  @TobiasS.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72032988/2887218) is sufficient if you don't mind hardcoding `A` and `B`.

Comment: In my case it is 3 types. I'm having some concerns with readability so currently looking into packages with utility types that could achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand your point about readability; could you explain? Any package would need to implement the type function you're talking about, so the question here would still be about how to implement it.  Unless you're now "seeking recommendations for software libraries", which turns this into an opinion question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this but I have the feeling there might be a shorter way:

```js
type New = {
   [K in Exclude<keyof A | keyof B, keyof Base>]: 
     K extends keyof A ? 
       K extends keyof B ? 
         B[K] | A[K] : A[K] 
     : B[K]
} & {
  extra: string
}

const test: New = {
  extra: '',
  type: 1,
  notShared: '',
  optional: "",
  base: '', // error
};
```